# Bootstrap navbar not collapsing to pills at the right point

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a couple of links on the left side and social media buttons on the right. The problem is that when i shrink the window, the links and buttons do not collapse into pills soon enough. Instead, the social media buttons from the right side go under the links on the left side. And then when the window is too narrow to fit the links, the pills appear.

How can I edit this so the navbar collapses at the right position?
Any help is much appreciated:)

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebsiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pills social-icons icon-circle icon-rotate">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you should share ALL relevant code ( HTML CSS )

Comment: can You add working snippet?

Comment: What you've posted works fine: http://www.codeply.com/go/ihvaYoT7j7

Comment: @ZimSystem thanks for the heads-up, my css file was the problem.

Comment: Great, next time post all of the relevant code. Otherwise people can't help! Also delete the question or accept an answer so others know it's been solved.

Comment: Didn't know I had to accept the answer. Newbie me:) Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you see 1000px, add your own width you want.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
      .navbar-header {
          float: none;
      }
      .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
          float: none !important;
      }
      .navbar-toggle {
          display: block;
      }
      .navbar-collapse {
          border-top: 1px solid transparent;
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
      }
      .navbar-fixed-top {
          top: 0;
          border-width: 0 0 1px;
      }
      .navbar-collapse.collapse {
          display: none!important;
      }
      .navbar-nav {
          float: none!important;
          margin-top: 7.5px;
      }
      .navbar-nav>li {
          float: none;
      }
      .navbar-nav>li>a {
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .collapse.in{
          display:block !important;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Btw I don't understand why my question was marked as "does not show any research effort". I'm banging my head against the wall for days about this and it is a specific problem, couldn't find anything similar. I'm not mad, I'm just a novice programmer and it's chalenging to learn to program on your own and those kind of comments could be discouraging for beginners. Anyways, thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class that , according to from the screen size , determines the width or more of the navbar .

```
@media ( max-width : 767px ) {
  .widthNavbar {
    width : 700px;
  }
}
```

or you can put the class is activated between two values ​​:

```
 @media ( min-width : 768px ) and ( max-width : 979px ) {
   .widthNavbar {
     width : 700px;
   }
 }
```